# Variable refuses to intalize in passwordverifier & driver

Tags: java

The basic concept was our passwords had to have an uppercase, lowercase and a number/digit. If it met that criteria the password was valid, if it didn't then invalidate the password.

Seemed simple enough, I have a love hate relationship with netbeans sometimes, but I managed to write out my program. Except I have ran into a slight catch.

In my verifier class I get a "might not have been intalized" warning on status:

```
      boolean status; // Validity status

    //Check to see if password is valid(contains one digit, one lowercase, one uppercase
    // may use if statement
      return status;
```

I get the same warning in my driver class for:

```
if (!PasswordVerifier.isValid(input))
```

I've looked over the code, tried rewriting it and to no avail, I'm confused. I feel like I'm overlooking something small, hence why I have posted this code here. I figure a second pair of eyes looking might find something that I clearly cannot find.

Entire Code Below

Driver

```
public class PasswordDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args){

                String input;  // To hold input

                // Create a Scanner object for keyboard input.
                Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

                // Get a password.
                System.out.print("Enter a password: ");
                input = keyboard.nextLine();

                // Check the password.
                if (!PasswordVerifier.isValid(input))
                        System.out.println("Invalid password.");
                else
                        System.out.println("Valid password.");

        }
}
```

Verifier

```
public class PasswordVerifier {

// Constant for minimum password length
   public static final int MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 8;

   /**
        isValid method
    */

   public static boolean isValid(String str)
   {
      boolean status; // Validity status

    //Check to see if password is valid(contains one digit, one lowercase, one uppercase
    // may use if statement
      return status;
   }

   /**
        hasUpperCase method
    */

   private static boolean hasUpperCase(String str)
   {
      boolean status = false; // Validity status

   // check to see if password contains at least one uppercase
   // may use a loop to check each character
      return status;
   }

   /**
        hasLowerCase method
    */

   private static boolean hasLowerCase(String str)
   {
      boolean status = false; // Validity status

     //check to see if password contains at least one lowercase
    //may use a loop to check each character 
      return status;
   }

   /**
        hasDigit method
    */

   private static boolean hasDigit(String str)
   {
      boolean status = false; // Validity status

    //check to see if password contains at least one digit
   //may use a loop to check each character 
      return status;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method `isValid` doesn't actually have any logic that would assign a boolean value to the variable `status` - you are declaring it and then returning it.

Comment: Yeah I just realized that a few moments ago, started working on it - getting late chalking it up to that overlook